# ios tableviews and json arrays

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, nsarray

---

This has been baffling me for a wile

I am successfully populating an array from a json call but the table view I want to poulate is not happening as the .

Can anyone see why?

I have tried a good few things but the array getting passed to the tableView is not getting populated with successfully retrieve json values

```
 - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    self.responseData = nil;

    NSArray* categories = [(NSDictionary*)[responseString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"categories"];
    [responseString release];


    //fetch the data
    for (NSDictionary* item in categories) {        
        NSString* c = [item objectForKey:@"CATEGORY_NAME"];
        [self.tableViewArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", c]];
    }

}

    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self loadData];
}

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [tableViewArray count];
}

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    NSInteger rowNumber = indexPath.row;
    NSString *stateName = [tableViewArray objectAtIndex:rowNumber];
    cell.textLabel.text = stateName;
    return cell;
 }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You selected %@",[self.tableViewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message: message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];

    [alert release];


}
```

EDIT

My .h is

```
@interface Medical_MeetingsViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    NSMutableArray *tableViewArray; 
    NSMutableData *responseData; 
    IBOutlet UITableView *tableViewCat;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *tableViewArray;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableData *responseData;

-(IBAction)loadData;

@end
```

is this correct?

Comment: Do you `[tableView reloadData]` after manipulating the array?

Comment: Thanks for This but I am now getting the problem in the edit below

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

In the designer, do you have your TableView connected via an IBOutlet? This reference is necessary so that your code can send it instructions.

Second, I don't see you calling `[tableview reloadData]` anywhere, you'll need to call that after you finish gathering the data.

Comment: Thanks for this, I have the tableview's outlets connected to a delegate and a datasource. I didnt have reloaddata but do now. I am now getting local declaration of tableView hides instance variable and I have     IBOutlet UITableView *tableView; in my .h

Comment: Simply give your IBOutlet another name.

Comment: Thanks again - as you can tell this is new to me I gave the IBOutlet another name in the .m and .h but its the same. Maybe you could please have a quick look at the .h above I just posted and tell me if it looks ok?

Comment: How did you rename the IBOutlet? Simply renaming in the editor is dangerous as you might miss some references. Rightclicking and choosing Refactor -> Rename is the preferred way. What I would do now is delete your IBOutlet (in code and IB), then recreate it.

Comment: And btw, my guess what went wrong would be that you only renamed the IBOutlet in your .m and .h file. You also have to update the connection in IB, which you probably didn't do.

Comment: ok I deleted and recreated all and refactored and renamed the local reference. now no errors but still no joy. Im going Bananas

Comment: Assuming your TableView is named tableViewCat, try `[self.tableViewCat reloadData];`

Comment: Also, are you `@synthesize`ing tableViewCat in your .m?